# I am getting an "exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver"

Tags: java, selenium, classloader

I have added `selenium-standalone.jar` & `selenium-java.jar` but still I am getting the following exception when running the basic program,

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver (wrong name:
>   org/openqa/selenium/Webdriver)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:488)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)

Please provide the solution with proper steps to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

This is where a dependency manager (like Maven) can help you, versus manual copying of libs.

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver`  can be found in **`selenium-api-<version>.jar`**

You will likely also need: `selenium-remote-driver-<version>.jar` and probably also `selenium-support-<version>.jar`, in addition to the `selenium-java-<version>.jar` you already have.

Comment: How to search in mavenrepository for everything you mentioned? I am facing the same issue and im using maven

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting good to use only one either standalone or java specific jars. Please give try by using only selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.0.jar i hope its works fine.

If you are trying to use java specific jars please provide all jars in downloaded zip file instead only that selenium-java.jar file. If you add all jar files in downloaded zip i hope this issue will resolved.

Thank You,
Murali