# class not found with selenium and java

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, classnotfoundexception

Im trying to learn selenium webdriver, but im running in to a problem.

I have made a very small test which looks like this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Flows {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/mn/Downloads/belikewater/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String baseUrl = "http://anywhere.c3a.dk/";


        driver.get(baseUrl);

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        driver.close();

    }
}
```

Im using gradle, and it looks like this:

```
group 'com.cetrea'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

group = 'com.cetrea'
version = '1.0.0'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.41.0')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

jar {
    manifest{
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.cetrea.flowtesting.Flows'
    }
}
```

I am getting the exception in

```
"main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I am using Mac OS, and have tried brew install chromedriver, but i couldnt locate the path to it, as i am very new to mac aswell, so i downloaded a zip and copied the chromedriver executeable in to my project.

Also cant remember how to get the full stack trace..

**
I must have been fucking something up. Running it with right clicking flows, and then pressing run flows.main() gave me another error, so atleast it has found the things it needed now. BUT i get this following error.

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.8.241036) on port 47434
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
May 07, 2018 11:39:22 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47434
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'cetreas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c9e:2c67:1d27:4e0b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:273)
    at com.cetrea.flows.Flows.main(Flows.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47434
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:240)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:158)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:238)
    ... 23 more
```

Could it be something like a firewall blocking it or something? It is a mac i have borrowed for half a year, so im not fully used to working on it yet.

Comment: Check this QA [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823506/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-w/47845104#47845104)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am getting an "exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111011/i-am-getting-an-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you run it?

I suspect this one isn't a Selenium issue. It looks suspiciously like that you are running your app something like this: `java -jar your-jar-name.jar`. But you need to supply all required jars on classpath.

A simple option would be to add following lines to your gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "com.cetrea.flowtesting.Flows"
```

Then run it as `gradle run`

Or you can ask gradle to copy all dependedency jars somehwere for you and then mention them all in your class path.

Should run successfully if you have downloaded the correct driver. Though you might still need some more dependencies as suggested in the answers referred in comments. But at the very least org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver should be already on your classpath.

Comment: Hmm i used intellij to run it, as a jar, and included the gradle build task first. 
Should i add that instead of the jar{} ?

Comment: I don't remember where the jar running option in IntelliJ is, but I guess it should be identical to `java -jar` from command line (which will only see your own classes in class path, but not dependencies). Using IntelliJ, you can either add 'application' plugin to your build.gradle file as described above and then run it as a gradle task. Or you can find Flows class in the Project window, mouse right click and choose Run Flows.main(). Provided that you created your IntelliJ project as gradle based, it should resolve class path properly.

Comment: Make a new folder, copy your sources to that folder, create new IntelliJ "Project from Existing Sources",  select your new folder, choose "Import project from existing model" and select gradle. Then you won't need to configure any custom running or building commands. IntelliJ will know how to build or run it correctly. And even if it does not (e.g. if you do some custom setup in your gradle file before running), you can always run a gradle task directly from IntelliJ and you won't lose any benefits of using an IDE (e.g. you still can debug your code).